# Parse string to get times

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am working on a project that is sending me a list of time in this format:

"[u'8:00', u'16:00', u'22:00']"

What I would like to know is how do I get an array of the times in javascript/jquery only from this string? I have tried various combinations of regular expressions and nothing seems to be able to extract the times. I am stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This string is accessible to you in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "[u'8:00', u'16:00', u'22:00']";
var times = str.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/g);
console.log(times); //=> ["8:00", "16:00", "22:00"]
```